# Change JavaScript on the fly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I use Internet Explorer (IE) to browse a website that uses some non-standardized JavaScript code. Particularly, `document.all` which is not supported in Chrome nor Firefox anymore.
My aim is to use Chrome or Firefox for browsing it, and this is possible if the `document.all` is replaced by `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` as per my research.

I don't have access to the server side in order to make this change, and I am looking for a way to do this modification in the client side. I tried to directly make the modification using DevTools of Chrome (Windows 10) but when I tried to save my changes I got an error saying that:

> change to this file were not saved to file system

Is there a way to resolve this? I also appreciate any alternative solutions.

Comment: I guess you'd have to do this either on a proxy, or browser extension level ... to be able to modify the code _before_ the browser starts parsing it.